# Getting value from another column when clicking targeted column JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user clicks on the 'Number' column I want to be able to get the 'Name' column value in the same row. So for example if I clicked on '999' I would want to be able to get David.

```js
$('#table').on('click', 'td:nth-child(2)', function()
{
 row = $(this).text();
  alert(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border id='table'>
 <thead>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Number</td>
  <td>Address</td>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>David</td>
   <td>999</td>
   <td>Street 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Bob</td>
   <td>555</td>
   <td>Street 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Jessica</td>
   <td>068</td>
   <td>Street 5</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()` to get the closest first td and its text.

If the wanted item is inside of the tr but you dont know the place or you want it dynamically, you can add a class or id to the name td and change the code to this `$(this).closest('tr').find('#WantedRowId').text()`

```js
$('#table').on('click', 'td:nth-child(2)', function() {
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border id='table'>
  <thead>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td>Address</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>David</td>
      <td>999</td>
      <td>Street 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>555</td>
      <td>Street 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jessica</td>
      <td>068</td>
      <td>Street 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works, but if you change the column order it won't work properly

Comment: @Adelin That is correct, you can add a id or class to the wanted td element and edit the code like this $(this).closest('tr').find('#WantedItem')

Answer (score 1):

You can find below a more appropriate solution that dynamically checks what is the `"Name"` column index and retrieves accordingly.

As such, if you insert other columns, like ID and what not, it'll still work without updating this specific logic.

```js
$('#table').on('click', 'td:nth-child(2)', function()
{
  $td = $(this);
  indexCol = $td.closest('table').find('td:contains(Name)').index()
  alert( $td.closest('tr').find('td').eq(indexCol).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border id='table'>
<thead>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Number</td>
  <td>Address</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>David</td>
<td>999</td>
<td>Street 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bob</td>
<td>555</td>
<td>Street 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jessica</td>
<td>068</td>
<td>Street 5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cool! Thx for giving me another method to use! Appreciate it